# my service return anonymous type data in JSON format, how to use it in angular 9 application as a string[]

Tags: angular, typescript

My service return data in JSON like

```
[
    {
        "txtUserRole": "FinAsst"
    },
    {
        "txtUserRole": "CSG"
    },
    {
        "txtUserRole": "PA"
    },
    {
        "txtUserRole": "ARTEAM"
    }
]
```

now I want to add all this role in a string array.
so i wrote a code like

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.generic.getUserRoles().toPromise().then(
      (jsonData) => {
        jsonData.forEach(element => {
          **// console.log(element['txtUserRole']);**  
          this.roles.push(element['txtUserRole']);
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

when i was logging with           **console.log(element['txtUserRole']);**

I am able to see that result as below in the console

```
FinAsst
CSG
PA
ARTEAM
```

but when in HTML using interpolation nothing is displayed.

```
 {{roles}}
```

what is the reason and what code needs to be changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume `getUserRoles()` function returns an observable. In that case, you could use the array [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to extract the values.

Controller

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.generic.getUserRoles().subscribe(
    jsonData => {
      this.roles = jsonData.map(item => item.txtUserRole)
    }
  );
}
```

And in the template either use `json` pipe or `*ngFor` directive to render the data.

```html
<span> {{ roles | json }} </span>
```

or

```html
<span *ngFor="let role of roles">
  {{ role }}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

in the html you need to use a loop to display the data:

```html
<div *ngFor="let role of roles">{{ role }}</div>
```

In case of a debug:

```html
{{ roles | json }}
```